# Passing Command-line arguments from C# to a external exe

Tags: c#, command-line, parameters

I have a similar problem as already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850802/piping-in-a-file-on-the-command-line-using-system-diagnostics-process). But I can not figure out, how the problem got solved. I have a program that get paramter the define a input and output file. Running this from Commend line, all works fine:

```
D:\Tools\siftDemoV4>siftWin32.exe -display < D:\tmp\SrcPgm\image000.pbm > result.pbm
```

But running via System.Diagnostics.Process, does not work. I get the error "Invalid command line argument: <" and after this a System.InvalidOperationException occurs.

```
var process = new Process()
{
   StartInfo =
   {
     Arguments = string.Format(@"-display < {0} > {1}", configuration.Source,
       configuration.Destination),
     FileName = configuration.PathToExternalSift,
     RedirectStandardError = true,
     RedirectStandardInput = true,
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     ErrorDialog = false,
   }
};

process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += OnProcessExited;
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

I already tried to write to process.StandardInput after I called process.Start(), but when using the debugger, the external program was sometime already finished (HasExited==true).

Can anybody explain how I can pass this special "<" ">" parameters to the programm?

Best Greetings!

By the way, I checked the path multiple time, they are correct.

Comment: If you already read the other thread, why didn't you read the [answer to your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/850856/880802), too? Hint: it's the first paragraph. And why `<` and `>` don't work is explained in the last one.

Comment: Everything after your `<` is no longer an argument to your application. Those are "switches" (so to speak) for the command line processor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Piping in a file on the command-line using System.Diagnostics.Process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850802/piping-in-a-file-on-the-command-line-using-system-diagnostics-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only parameter you need is `-display` Others are not parameters to the program and should be handled by you by using `RedirectStandardInput` and `RedirectStandardOutput`

E.g

- read the file `D:\tmp\SrcPgm\image000.pbm`
- write to `StandardInput` of your process
- read from `StandardOutput` of your process
- write to `result.pbm`

[Using command redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

Comment: Ok I tried this, but now I got an onther error: Error: Input is not a standard raw PGM file. But everthing I do is process.StandardInput.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile)) and Flush()+Close(). I does not change anything on the content on the file.

Comment: If solved the problem with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956274/how-to-pass-filename-to-standardinput-process-in-c). The problem was solved by reading the file into a string, instead of a byte[]. Does anybody know why? Thanks to L.B.