# Redirect binary data from Process.StandardOutput causes corrputed data

Tags: c#, encoding, command-line, process

On top of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978390/passing-command-line-arguments-from-c-sharp-to-a-external-exe/8978450) problem, I have another. I try to get binary data from a external process, but the data(a image) seems to be corrupted. The screenshot below shows the corruption: The left image was done by executing the program on command line, the right one from code. 
[image]

My Code so far:

```
var process = new Process
{
  StartInfo =
  {
    Arguments = string.Format(@"-display"),
    FileName = configuration.PathToExternalSift,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
  },
  EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (ProcessErrorDataReceived);

process.Start();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

//Reads in pbm file.
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(configuration.Source))
{
  process.StandardInput.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
  process.StandardInput.Flush();
  process.StandardInput.Close();
}
//redirect output to file.
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(configuration.Destination, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
  process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}

process.WaitForExit();
```

Is this some kind of encoding problem? I used the Stream.CopyTo-Approach as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143281/capturing-binary-output-from-process-standardoutput) in order to avoid there problems.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I might have a hint. Use a hex editor (I recommend fhred) and look at the output file and the input file. I bet whats happening is that the corruption is coming from newline characters being translated.

Comment: You can't redirect binary data, only text.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. First of all, its possible to redirect binary data. I found the answer just a minute ago. But due to my reputation I can't answer the question now. I will post it later. So far: The problem was not redirecting the output, it was on reading in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. The redirection of the output was correct, the reading of the input seems to be the problem. So I changed the code from:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(configuration.Source))
{
  process.StandardInput.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
  process.StandardInput.Flush();
  process.StandardInput.Close();
}
```

to

```
using (var fileStream = new StreamReader(configuration.Source))
{
  fileStream.BaseStream.CopyTo(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
  process.StandardInput.Close();
}
```

Not it works!

For all the people that might have the same problem, here the corrected code:

```
var process = new Process
{
  StartInfo =
  {
    Arguments = string.Format(@"-display"),
    FileName = configuration.PathToExternalSift,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
  },
  EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (ProcessErrorDataReceived);

process.Start();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

//read in the file.
using (var fileStream = new StreamReader(configuration.Source))
{
    fileStream.BaseStream.CopyTo(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
    process.StandardInput.Close();
}
//redirect output to file.
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(configuration.Destination, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}

process.WaitForExit();
```