# How to change variables of a .exe file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exe

I want my program in Visual C# to allow the user to generate a portable .exe file to be run on another user's computer, with the portabe .exe receiving the values the first user inserted. I don`t want to use a configuration file or any other file to store the input values to be then read because I want the .exe to be a single file. I have the main and the second program (future portable executable) 
as different projects on the same solution. Is there a way to modify values of the portable .exe or does a new program needs to be compiled on the fly?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you looking for, but passing values to .exe without configuration file can be done by passing values in command line argument.

Comment: @Amit sensible solutions ... Where is all entertainment value of recompiling exe on a fly or hacking values in memory :)

Comment: @Kreator [Passing Command-line arguments from C# to a external exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978390/passing-command-line-arguments-from-c-sharp-to-a-external-exe)  will it help ?

Comment: upvote for commandline args, and shortcut.

Comment: @Kreator  FYI, If your portable .exe does have liberty to read data from web (from specific URL) you can always update values on that URL thus your portable .exe will get changed values without re-compiling!

Comment: @Amit Sorry, I really didn`t know that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To formally answer the question.

You can convert the assembly to IL, search and replace and recompile. However, if you are building this application, you should really consider the need and use case for such very thoroughly.

If you need just to modify the behavior of an application, you have a plethora of options.

- Registry (can be remotely done)
- A config file (though you ruled this out)
- You could use a login method to a resouce

  - Wcf for instance
  - Active Directory
  - A network DB
- Rebuild you app for these users
- Msbuild with a batch file to tweak something
- A pre build script

If you are really tricky you "might" be able to track down the offset of an int and tweak it. However this seems very unreliable

Or if you really have your heart set on this, see the following and associated questions

[Modify Emdeded String in C# compiled exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742583/modify-emdeded-string-in-c-sharp-compiled-exe)

[Is it possible to Add/Remove/Change an embedded resource in .NET DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545858/is-it-possible-to-add-remove-change-an-embedded-resource-in-net-dll)

**Update** from *Ben Voigt* Comments

> *Win32* Resources can be changed after being embedded in an *EXE*. *.NET*
>   `System.Resources` can only be changed before embedding. C# applications
>   are compatible with both kinds, but the distinction is very important
>   The The necessary function is [UpdateResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You can embed resources and later change them without recompiling.

Comment: After a bit more research I should clarify -- Win32 Resources can be changed after being embedded in an EXE.  .NET `System.Resources` can only be changed before embedding.  C# applications are compatible with both kinds, but the distinction is very important.

Comment: The necessary function is [`UpdateResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049(v=vs.85).aspx)   C++ example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources

Comment: @TheGeneral Thank you very much for the detailed and complete answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can typically append to an `.exe` without breaking it and then read the data in upon execution.

See: [appending data to an exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795446/appending-data-to-an-exe)

Comment: Yes, both using the Win32 Resource Functions made for this purpose and rolling your own are totally feasible.  (The Win32 Resource Functions provide a directory/catalog for you so resources can be read and written by name... but using the existing scheme also means your data can be found by existing tools)